# run a non-mapreduce work in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I wonder whether it is possible to run a non-mapreduce job in Hadoop, say a java program printing "hello word". If so, would you please show me an example?
Thank you very much.

Comment: ummm Hadoop is a database ... it's not an operating system

Comment: But we can submit mapreduce work to it, right. I saw examples online as conf.setMapperClass(Map.class); conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class); conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class); But if it is a simple java, there would be no Map or Reduce class. It has only a Main function

Comment: basic idea of map-reduce is to split a task into subtasks and process them in parallel. when you submit a job to hadoop, it will read the input and split it and pass each split to mappers and them pass the result to the reducers. 'hello word' is not the idea behind hadoop, that is why we have 'word count' as the basic example in hadoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a jar and run it with `hadoop jar`:

```
[root@localhost hellworld]# cat HelloWorld.java 

public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
}}


[root@localhost hellworld]# javac HelloWorld.java 
[root@localhost hellworld]# jar cvf helloworld.jar HelloWorld.class 

[root@localhost hellworld]# ~/Downloads/hadoop-2.1.0-beta/bin/hadoop jar helloworld.jar HelloWorld
Hello World!
```

Comment: Since this answer was accepted over mine, I'm assuming that all the OP wanted was to add the hadoop jars to the classpath. I thought the question was asking about how to do distributed computing in hadoop that is NOT a MapReduce workflow.

Answer (score 2):

With Hadoop 1.x and prior it is not possible. However, this is exactly what YARN is designed for. MapReduce 2.0 is built on top of YARN.

YARN is an abstraction for distributed resource management. Check it out [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html)

**EDIT**: Actually I lied, in Hadoop 1.x and prior it is still somewhat possible to do non MapReduce jobs with some hackery. If you look at the way [Apache Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org) was implemented, they hooked into the MapReduce framework to do task distribution. The Mapper just becomes a container for them to launch their real code. But in my humble opinion, that was not an elegant solution. Since YARN was released, there is also an implementation of Giraph on YARN which (again IMHO) is much more elegant.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try it first.